# Passing {id} when button is clicked

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have setup a controller - product which allows me to look up a product

```
url.com/product/{id}
```

When I click a button on the product page. say, to add to cart which takes me to another page. What is the best way to pass on this {id}. Becuase then I want to reference this $id in a controller to look up pricing via .

`$price = Prices::where('id',$id)`

Is this a good method?

`Route::get('/prices/{id}', 'PriceController@lookup');`

then

```
<a href="/make-offer/{{$listings->id}}"><button class="btn btn-success">View Price</button></a>
```

Only issue with this is I get Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI:/prices/{id}

Comment: check whether `$listings->id` is empty. or `$listings` is a collection?

Comment: View the html in debugger in browser and let us know what the link actually shows as. Plus your question references three different routes, /product, /make-offer, and /prices. Which are you trying to hit in your link?

Answer (score 3):

change

```
<a href="/make-offer/{{$listings->id}}"><button class="btn btn-success">View Price</button></a>
```

to

```
<a href="/prices/{{$listings->id}}"><button class="btn btn-success">View Price</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A get route is fine to look up a single product price. You could also store the product_id in a session variable. You could use session()->push() to store multiple product id's in a session array so you can later build a cart to display total prices and an itemized list.